# Multiple files upload without Html5

Tags: jquery, html

How we can enable multi file upload in the legacy browser With Drag/drop possibility also .

Answer (score 1):

Google for: *cross browser multi upload*

and the first result is:

http://code.google.com/p/noswfupload/

noSWFUpload

Multiple files upload **without** SWF objects, applets Java, or other third parts plug-ins.
Features

> 100% browser and W3 compatibility thanks to graceful enhancement
>
> no extra libraries dependency
>
> simple and low level API
>
> wide browser compatibility in 3.63 KB (minified and gzipped)

Compatibility

- Internet Explorer 5.5 (probably 5 too), 6, 7, and 8
- FireFox 3 or greater
- Google Chrome 1.0 (V2 Coming Soon)
- Opera 8, 9, and 10
- Safari 3, Safari 4 (current beta)
  other browsers via unobtrusive iframe

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) jQuery plugin has almost everything you need.

## Features

- Multiple file upload
- Drag & Drop support
- Resumable uploads
- No browser plugins (e.g. Adobe Flash) required
- Cross-site file uploads

## Browser Support (tested versions)

- Google Chrome - 7.0+
- Apple Safari - 4.0+
- Mozilla Firefox - 3.0+
- Opera - 10.0+
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 6.0+