# Coldfusion post form to cfc asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coldfusion

First of all, let me start off by saying the product I am developing will be used by people that don't inherently have access to HTML5. Some of the individuals will still be using IE8. I have a form like the following:

```
<form action="ee.cfc?method=xlsupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
    <input type="file" id="xlsfile" name="xlsfile" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload XLS">
</form>
```

and in my .cfc file I have a function that processes the file and translates it to a structure (which will then upload to a database after the user validates the data). Currently I have it set to `<cfreturn SerializeJSON(dataset,true)>`. However, when I submit the form it opens the cfc file and shows the JSON structure. I have done plenty of form submits, etc. in JQuery before, but is there a way to do this without JQuery? One would hope Coldfusion would have the capability to do this, (though of course I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't).

Comment: Your form action is changing the page to that location. You need to use an Ajax / XHR request to get that information back into this page. CF Has Ajax functions, but you are better off using jquery or native javascript. As usual, Ben Nadel has a great post on it. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1244-coldfusion-jquery-and-ajax-file-upload-demo.htm

Comment: You can skip the js stuff altogether and submit to a .cfm page that calls the cfc upload method.

Comment: Just because you are submitting a form to a CFC does not mean you are doing so asynchronously.If you want to send data asynchronously, you need to use AJAX. The easiest way to do this is by using a JS library like jQuery. Why do you not want to use jQuery? Why would you prefer not to use a tool that is designed to handle the problem you have? That is like saying: 'I need to cut this piece of wood in half, I have used a saw to do this in the past, but would prefer not to use it this time'.

Comment: (Edit) Yes, can you clarify your requirements? Which type of upload do you really want: synchronous OR asynchronous? If you need the latter, why not JQuery? Browser support for asynch file uploads varies. Prior to HTML5 some sort of helper tool was required (flash, iframes, etcetera). Last I checked, [CF's ajax does not support it](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm). Plus it is old and clunky. What is your issue with jQuery? [A few plugins claim to support IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996835/multiple-files-upload-without-html5).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I ended up passing the form to a new page, similar to below for confirmation. And the reason I couldn't use jQuery was b/c I have heard that $.ajax struggles with file input types in non HTML5, due to issues with IE8, which unfortunately most of my users have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asynchronously post is only useful if you want the user to interact with the webpage the form is on while in the background uploading the form. If this is what you want you should/can use jquery.

If synchronously is also an option. Then upload the form to a .cfm file, run the cfc on the .cfm document wait for the response of the component and then redirect the .cfm document using cflocation to a webpage that informs the visitor its upload has been processed. (use cflocation to prevent multiple submits).

e.g.

```
<form action="upload.cfm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" id="xlsfile" name="xlsfile" required>
<input type="submit" value="Upload XLS">
</form>
```

upload.cfm

```
<cfset yourComponent = createObject('component','/cfc/ee')>
<cfset response = yourComponent.functionName(form.xlsfile)>
<Cflocation url="done.cfm">
```

done.cfm

```
<html>....</html>
```